# Tensor product of representation of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ Identity

Tags: quantum-spin, group-theory, representation-theory

I have troubles to understand an equation, which was stated in a lecture. Consider the spin-j representation $V_{j}$ of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ with its standard basis

$$\{\vert j,m\rangle\}_{-j\leq m\leq j}$$

Now, consider the fundamental representation $V_{\frac{1}{2}}$.It was then stated that

$$\vert\uparrow\rangle^{\otimes 2j}=\vert j,j\rangle$$
where $\vert\uparrow\rangle=\vert 1/2,1/2\rangle$ is one of the two basis vectors of $V_{1/2}$. I cannot see why this is the case. I know that $V_{1/2}^{\otimes 2j}$ is a submodule of $V_{j}$, as a consequence of the Clebsch-Gordan decomposition, but I do not see how to obtain the equality from above. I guess, the result has something to do with the Clebsch-Gordan coefficients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have it backwards: $V_j$ (dimension $2j+1$) is a submodule of $V^{\otimes 2j}_{1/2}$ (dimension $2^{2j}$).

The state  $|\uparrow, \ldots, \uparrow\rangle$  is the highest weight state of both the $V_j$ module and the $V^{\otimes 2j}_{1/2}$. In other words it is the unique state with  the highest $m$ spin value $m=j$ in both the larger and the smaller space. Applying step-down ladder opertors keeps the resulting states in $V_j$ so $|\uparrow, \ldots, \uparrow\rangle$   must coincide  with $|j,j\rangle$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. Would you be so kind to have a look over my follow-up question (https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/679806/confusion-about-tensor-products-of-states-in-the-fundamental-representation-of)?